# edit corner case, check null in c#

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, datagrid, null

My code is save datagrid to csv. when process to

```
value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
```

Error message is the following:**System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get return null.**

Then, I add corner case to check cell is null and replace those cells by "Null".

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (rw.Cells[i].Value == System.DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            swOut.Write("Null");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But the error message is there still.

The following is my code:

```
 public void writeCSV(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFile)
        {
            //test to see if the DataGridView has any rows
            if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
            {
                string value = "";
                DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
                 StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (rw.Cells[i].Value == System.DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            swOut.Write("Null");
                        }
                    }
                }

                //write header rows to csv
                for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)

                {

                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.Write(",");
                    }
                    swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                }

                swOut.WriteLine();

                //write DataGridView rows to csv
                for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)

                {

                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.WriteLine();
                    }

                    dr = gridIn.Rows[j];

                    for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)

                    {

                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            swOut.Write(",");
                        }

                        value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                        //replace comma's with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                        //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                        swOut.Write(value);
                    }
                }
                swOut.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: try: `if (rw.Cells[i].Value == null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code appears to work… IF the `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` is `false`! The default is `true`.  If the grid allows users to add rows, the code will crash at the line…

```
value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
```

when it hits the “new” row. The cells in the “new” row are `null` not `DBNull.` If you want to allow the user to add rows (which I assume is the case since the code is stripping out commas and new lines), then the code will need to check for this “new” row and ignore it when exporting the grid.

With that said, I believe you are making this way more complicated than it has to be. The goal is to export the cells in a `DataGridView` to a comma delimited file (CSV). This can be done with much less code and still avoid the dreaded null values in the cells.

From the perspective of the CSV file, if a cell is “null” that means that we want to output an “empty” string to the CSV file. This will maintain the column schema. Therefore, a simple double loop through the grids cells is all that needs to be done. While looping through the cells and writing the values to the file, a simple check is needed before we try and grab a cells `value.ToString()`. If `value` is null, the code will crash as a `null` does not have a `ToString()` method. Therefore if `value` “is” `null` then write an empty string to the file… problem solved!

Therefore, to help, I recommend you use a different strategy to export the grids cells. There appears no reason for the `dr` variable nor the `value` variable. In addition, I would assume that the cells text does “NOT” contain commas (,). If you “know” the grid is going to be exported to a CSV file… I would set the grids cells such that the user would “not” be able to type a comma. Therefore, the code below does not strip out commas or new lines. Hope that makes sense.

```
public void writeCSV(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFile) {
   try {
     using (StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile)) {
       //write header rows to csv
       for (int i = 0; i < gridIn.Columns.Count; i++) {
         swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[i].HeaderText);
         if (i < gridIn.ColumnCount - 1) {
           swOut.Write(",");
         }
         else {
           swOut.WriteLine();
         }
       }
       //write DataGridView rows to csv
       for (int row = 0; row < gridIn.Rows.Count; row++) {
         if (!gridIn.Rows[row].IsNewRow) {
           for (int col = 0; col < gridIn.Columns.Count; col++) {
             if (dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null) {
               swOut.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
             }
             else {
               swOut.Write("");
             }
             if (col < gridIn.Columns.Count - 1) {
               swOut.Write(",");
             }
             else {
               swOut.WriteLine();
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and edited code. They perfectly solved my problem.